# Drag-and-drop a new series onto an Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003, drag-and-drop

In Excel 2003, I can select a new data series and drag it onto an existing chart to add it to that chart. In Excel 2007 I can't. Does anyone know if this functionality was removed or if it is available in another way? It was quite convenient.

If it's been removed, does anyone know why? I'm assuming it's to do with a change in how Excel handles series data.

Comment: I like to use Paste Special to make sure Excel uses the data as I intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to drag and drop new data onto an Excel chart was deprecated from Excel 2007 and later.

You can copy paste (copy the data you want to add, select the chart and paste).

Comment: Good enough for me!